# Rails - Build does not create a record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to add authentications controller for my current devise system, in order to provide multiple logins with facebook and twitter. 
To do that, I'm following this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

My problem is, for the person, who hasn't registered yet, and trying to register with twitter. 
So I need to create both user and authentication for that.

My code is the following:

```
      user = User.new
      token = omni['credentials'].token
      token_secret = omni['credentials'].secret
      user.provider = omni.provider
      user.uid = omni.uid

      user.authentications.build(:provider => omni['provider'], :uid => omni['uid'], :token => token, :token_secret => token_secret)

      if user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)                
      else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
```

So at the end of the registration process, the new user is created. However in the database, I don't see any twitter authentication record with respect to that user.

Is that because of the user.authentications.build ?

That would be great if you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a data point: The railscasts you're referring to references Omniauth pre-1.0, which had a slighly different strategy than what that railscsts reference. (Note: I'm using the exact method you're referencing on a live site ). In this case, the build calls "apply_omniauth" -

Make sure you've created (as they reference in the video), a registrations controller which builds the resource. Here is my current working example:

```
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
  end

  private

  def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth]
      # apply omniauth calls the user model and applies omniauth session to the info
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])

      #
      @user.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

However, you still need to create the authentication record, here is my exact call:

```
current_user.authentication.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So basically, besides the registration controller, you're using create! instead of build ?

Comment: Correct. As Jesse notes below, the reason why is the difference between build and create.

Comment: yes thank you very much it worked. And I wrote a tutorial with all of the process with updated gems and rails version: http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because of build

```
User.build # allocates a new record for you
User.create # allocates and then saves a new record for you
```

So I think you want

```
user.authentications.create(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                            :uid => omni['uid'], 
                            :token => token, 
                            :token_secret => token_secret)
```

In addition, you should handle the case where the create does not save (validation problem)

Comment: But for example in the case user authenticates with twitter is asked to enter e-mail, before it is saved. In that phase user might be cancel the registration process. Then won't I have the authentication record for nil user ?

Comment: Btw, in that issue I got this error: "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved" because I haven't saved my user yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you are using Devise+Omniauth , you could take a look at this more recent [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised). There is a native support of OmniAuth in the new version of Devise gem .

Comment: Yes, I built my web site with respect to that tutorial. But now I want to provide multiple authentications. That's why I'm creating the new controller

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because of build, it is use to build a record without saving it in the database (like new).

If in your model you have a `User` `has_many :authentications` , you can set the `autosave` option to true to automatically save the authentications when you are saving the user :

`has_many :authentications, autosave: true`

Comment: No, I added autosave, but it still only creates the user :/

Comment: o_O, it could be a bug, are you using the last version of RoR ?